# Modeling Interest-only Mortgages

Tags: interest-rates, probability, modeling, real-estate

Can we infer a range of future all-in costs for I/O ARMs with current index forward curves?

Essentially, just taking a worksheet like [this](http://pistulka.com/Excel_Shared/APR-ARM.xlsx) and adding some type of ramping capability after the fixed rate period ends. I'm interested in how quickly ARM rates adjust to changes in indices, and implications for borrowers given market expectations about the future path of monetary policy decisions.

On a less quantitative note, loan characteristics are hard to find; all of the premium sources at my disposal focus on capital markets. Margin is likely some function of FICO, LTV etc. Can we reliably infer some of these from publicly available data? Every underwriter has slightly different standards, but I'm sure there are white papers out there somewhere.

Advanced applications would include rate stressing, i.e. putting Fitch's forward LIBOR curve into a given amortization profile and seeing how much P&I we end up owing.

Changes to property values over time would be very interesting to model as well - if I take out an I/O loan, LIBOR rises in lockstep with Fed Funds, and the underlying property appreciates or depreciates ten percent, what does the IRR look like?

First post on this forum - happy to be here. Please give feedback if this is off-topic so I can more meaningfully contribute moving forward. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should try to model it properly in a quantitative model that allows you to account for FICOs, LTVs, etc.

Take a look at this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3135366). The authors in section 3.3 solve a model with an interest only ARM. You can use the simulations of such a model to understand how IRRs change if you change assumptions regarding how property prices change, federal funds rate, etc.